# pyqrcode.create does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to merge a Qr Code onto a pdf.  When I split the code into two separate scripts it works fine.  I am new to phython any help is appreciated. I am running this on RHEL 7.4 in Phyton 2.7
Yes I know it's old but it is a 3rd party server and I cannot upgrade it.

```
[user@myserver scripts]$ python pdf_test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_test3.py", line 28, in <module>
    qcode = pyqrcode("http://www.weather.com","/cfg/test.png")
  File "pdf_test3.py", line 8, in __init__
    qrCode = self.create(url)
AttributeError: pyqrcode instance has no attribute 'create'
```

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from pyqrcode import QRCode
import png
import sys

class pyqrcode(QRCode):
    def __init__(self, url,fileOutputDir):
        qrCode = self.create(url)
        # create qr code and save it as a svg image
        qrCode.png(fileOutputDir, scale=1)

class PDF(FPDF):
    def __init__(self,imageFileName):
        # file name, left,top,heght,width
        self.image(imageFileName, 200,1,20,20)
        self.cell(30, 10, 'Title', 1, 0, 'C')

    # Page footer
    def footer(self):
        # Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        self.set_y(-15)
        # Arial italic 8
        self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
        # Page number
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C')

# Instantiation of inherited class
qcode = pyqrcode("http://www.weather.com","/cfg/test.png")

pdf = PDF()
pdf.alias_nb_pages()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Times', '', 12)
for i in range(1, 5):
    pdf.cell(0, 10, 'Hello World.' + str(i), 0, 1)
pdf.output('test.pdf', 'F')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is saying that your own `pyqrcode` instance has no create function, which it does not. Also, best not to name a class with the same name as a module

You can fix that by importing the create function

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from pyqrcode import QRCode
from pyqrcode import create as create_qrcode
import png
import sys

class PyQRcode(QRCode):
    def __init__(self, url,fileOutputDir):
        qrCode = create_qrcode(url)
```

Comment: I guess I only copied the create from the other script that was working. Now I get an error on the pdf.  pdf = PDF()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: duh I forgot to supply the Parameter to the pdf instance.